# Android Studio Gradle project refresh failed - Error host is down

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried many solutions to run Android Studio 2.3.3 on macOS 10.12 but this error still keeps showing and won't let me start a new project.

In the Event Log it says Gradle sync failed: Host is down. When I remove the gradle directories and invalidate caches it still has no effect.

Can anybody please suggest a way around this? All of the solutions I have seen posted in the forum haven't been successful so far.

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall settings to make sure it is not blocked.  I have the same issue because I have blocked this with my firewall:

[image: Android Studio via java.org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon wants to connect to jcenter.bintray.com on TCP port 443 (https) “java.org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon” has no code signature. The executable can be maliciously modified without being detected.]

In my experience Android Studio requires an internet connection and unfettered access to the internet in order for you to develop anything.  Hopefully this will improve with future versions.

There may be other ways to run the application without relying on Android Studio or gradle build process.  One potential way might be to use the Unity platform.  Otherwise you might try a google search for "build and run android app without gradle".